# How to convert the 'http:////someurl/' into http://someurl/' in Internet Explorer only-js

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer

I'm trying to load certain files for my application using the require.js. everything works fine in chrome and FF, but when i checked the Network tab in IE, it shows status as "Aborted" for some files, reason is the incorrect path.

```
Ex:
  http:////someurl/index/main.js
  http:////someurl/index/index2.js
  http:////someurl/index/test.js
```

IE is not able to convert the 4 slash after the 'http' automatically into 2, like the chrome and FF and hence results into "aborted" or file not found.
here is my main.js base url:

```
require.config({
baseUrl: "http://" + context, // where context = "//someurl/index/"
path: {
    path1: /someurl/index/path1,
    path2: /someurl/index/path2,
    path3: /someurl/index/path3,
 }
});
```

How to convert the `http:////someurl/index/main.js` into `http://someurl/index/main.js` in IE so that it renders the correct path. I also tried taking this url and pasting it in the browser and it works fine. Only on page load the IE fails to identify these files and throws errors.
Any ideas how to solve this issue??
Thanks!!

Comment: It seems like the better fix is to avoid generating those URLs with too many slashes in the first place.

Comment: If `context` always begins with two slashes, just change `"http://"` to `"http:"`.  If it *doesn't*, then you need to go figure out why that is.

Comment: @MattBall:  i tried to get rid of those slashes and it threw : Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined for all those files. so instead aborted status, i get 404 on all those files whose base url is set to above...

Comment: Have you tried removing the first slash in the path?
 path1: /someurl/index/path1 to path1: someurl/index/path1,

Comment: `Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined` is an _entirely_ different problem...

Comment: sorry, my bad in explaining the error: the removal of the extra '//'  results into requirejs adding a '.js' extension to all the mustache files and causes the 'jquery not defined' error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your code:

```
 baseUrl: "http://" + context, // where context = "//someurl/index/"
```

This isn't an IE problem, it's that your URL is invalid with four slashes in it. Okay, so maybe Chrome and Firefox manage to cope with it and work out what you mean... that doesn't mean it's right, and it doesn't mean you should be doing anything special for IE to fix it.

The answer is obvious really. You just need to have fewer slashes.

You say that `context` starts with `//`, so why not just drop the `//` from the `http://` part. Problem solved; valid URL. Should work in all browsers.

I guess it's possible that `context` might not always start with a `//`, in which case maybe you're adding the `//` on `http:` as well just in case. If that's what's happening here, then the solution is to check when building the string so you can decide whether to add the `//` or not.

Comment: the context variable comes from a json file, which i tried removing the extra '//', this resulted into surprisingly into new error: requirejs adding the .js extension to the end of all mustache files. all js files renders correctly but it fails only for .mu files and in IE only(chrome, ff) works fine!! any idea of this weird behaviour?

Comment: Not a clue, but it sounds unlikely to be directly related to the original problem.